# an error happened when query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexoutofboundsexception

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "content": {
                    "value": "远磐",
                    "boost": 5757544300000000000
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "title": {
                    "value": "远磐",
                    "boost": 5757544300000000000
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "title": {
                    "value": "互联",
                    "boost": 6456151
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "content": {
                    "value": "杭州远磐互联科技有限公司",
                    "boost": 3.3149317e+37
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

When I create the elasticsearch query on search the result, the error happend.

I have no idea about this errors.

***errors:***

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException[docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=158 (got docID=2147457971)]
```

***and the score of all hits is zero.***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLGnF.jpg)
the whole errors:

Any help please!

Regards

Comment: why you have another bool inside your must? it would be more helpful if  you can upload your requirement and your sample document?

Comment: the requirement can be described as the sql as follows:

select document
from db
where (field1="XXXX" or field2="*****") and (field1="$$$$" or field3="&&&&")

Comment: I am posting the correct query as answer, hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as answer as it can't be posted as comment. Here is the optimized query.
It is better to use filters instead of query as filters are cached. You should avoid giving such large numbers as boost as it is resource hungry. Try relatively smaller numbers.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "content": "远磐"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "title": "远磐"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "content": "互联"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "title": "杭州远磐互联科技有限公司"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "content": "远磐",
            "boost": 10
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "title": "远磐",
            "boost": 5
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "content": "互联",
            "boost": 3
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "title": "杭州远磐互联科技有限公司",
            "boost": 20
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "from":0,
  "size":10
}
```

Comment: Another question is that all the terms has it's own weight, but filter does not support  boost.

Comment: you can convert this query to a bool query, put these filters into must part and apply boost to them in should part of bool query, you can read more here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: I've converted my query to a bool query and put all the must terms in the filters, but it also has the same error. Is the weight of the term is too large to lead some errors on ElasticSearch boost? The max weight of the term is about 3.3149317e+37.

Comment: which elasticsearch version are you using? if you are not using elaslticsearch 2.3.0 you should consider upgrading to that and re-indexing all your data.

Comment: yeah large numbers create problems for boosting but Lucene handles them in latest versions which is used by ElasticSearch for indexing the data.

Comment: I think I should change my elasticsearch version. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel if that solves your problem, please do reply back